# Graphql - Retrieve boolean type inside Mutation

Tags: graphql

I have a `logOut` mutation inside a `schema.graphql`

like so :

```
type AuthenticationController {
  logOut: Boolean!
}
```

I'm trying to create a mutation & get back the Boolean value from it

```
mutation Logout {
  accounts {
    auth {
      logOut: logOut() {
        Boolean
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can I query this boolean as it has no variable name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info you shared (schema) is very limited, so I'm not sure I understood.
But looks like you are mixing some things up.

The syntax of this `logOut: logOut() { ... }` is [aliasing](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases), and it's redundant since you use the exact same field name.

In addition, since logOut is not an object but a scalar, this should work:

```
mutation Logout {
  accounts {
    auth {
      logOut
    }
  }
}
```